# ModelCheckPoint Keras does'nt create any checkpoint file.(Colab)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

Created checkpoint:

```
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd()+"/model.h5")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_mean_squared_error', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, mode='min')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',  metrics=['mse',r_square])
print(K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

Callbacks:

```
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1000,verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

**No files were created in the directory.**

Tried all possibilities and also gone through some StackOverflow answers but nothing useful found.

And I'm using Colab.

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: Try using os.getcwd() + "\\model.h5"

Comment: Tried it but no use..

Comment: Any chance anything in the code could change working directory? Normally this should not be happening, but obviously you don't get the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `checkpoint_path = "model.h5"`?

Colab might prevent you from writing to certain folders.